# SAS Addin in Tableau

Tags: sas, tableau-api

I am very new to Tableau. I want to prepare a report with pivot tables in tableau which can be updated weekly from sas datasets, as we can do in excel with sas addin. Is there any way to do it in tableau? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. But you can export to a common database, such as SQL or SQLite and then connect it from there.  http://community.tableausoftware.com/thread/107506?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: That's a 4 year old thread - it looks from later threads that they did add the support.

Comment: Thanks...and interesting. I'll have to give that a try in the next few days. I wonder if it requires a SAS server or just a SAS dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ODBC driver to connect to a SAS dataset.  I believe that is something extra that you need to get separately from the SAS Corporation, though.  http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/tableau-and-sas-odbc

Comment: The ODBC driver itself is free, but in order to use it, you would have to point it to one of the following: A SAS/Share Server, A SAS SPD Server or a local workstation (can not be server license)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use indexes or anything fancy on the SAS datasets, you can always just export the SAS dataset to a CSV and point Tableau at that.  If you can't point Tableau at the CSV directly, then create an ODBC connection to the CSV file and point Tableau at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Action in Tableau to point to a SAS stored process that returns the data as a table.